# 500 Error in DotNet Core 3.1 with Ocelot Gateway

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, microservices, ocelot

I'm implementing a gateway to work on Azure Portal. The problem is my Ocelot which works perfectly fine on localhost, but on Azure it always gives 500 Internal Error.

My Ocelot:

```
{
  "Routes": [
     {

      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/AuthApi",

      "DownstreamScheme": "https",

      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [

        {
          "Host": https://myazurenameapp.azurewebsites.net
        }
      ],

      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/token",

      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "Baseurl": https://mygatewayazureapp.azurewebsites.net
  }
}
```

Is there anything I need on Azure Portal?

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Before publishing a microservice application in azure. We need to create a separate app service for each service and API gateway.

As normal, Publish it directly from the VS 2019.
Change the endpoints from the local host to Azure endpoints in ocelot.json before publishing the operation.

Try to check the below things to avoid errors in azure:

- In the Azure app service, enable **https**, if you enabled https in your project.
- Kindly set a startup project as multiple projects and choose all projects in the list as start.

Comment: Hey, Did the above provided steps worked for you to resolve the issue?